# HighChart vs D3.Chart or C3.Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts, c3.js

I require some charting options in my CMS Application. I will be using Pie Charts, Area Charts, Column Charts, Bar Charts and Gauge Charts.
From all options available on internet, I found C3.js chart and HighCharts.js good for my project. Apart from licensing what are the differences between these two?
Which option is better?

Thanks

Comment: d3 is best, but you have to build all charts from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

#### Possibilities

***d3.js*** is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.

***c3.js*** is a Javascript library which makes it easy to generate D3-based charts (less code to write).

***highchart*** is a Javascript charting framework.

#### Which one use?

> I will be using Pie Charts, Area Charts, Column Charts, Bar Charts and Gauge Charts

I think all of them are suitable for you. I will check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks) comparison table to see which features have each of them. Check out also examples and documentations to know the frameworks and learn how use them.